# Eclipse - Syntax Error Messages Appearing In-Line - What settings change will fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings

To anyone who knows the eclipse config settings really well, how do I fix this? Whenever I make a syntax error, it pops a message line into the actual code and it is extremely annoying. I have not made any changes to the settings other than visual/color themes.

What it looks like
[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 7):

In order **not to display errors as so-called *code minings* in the Java editor**, you must do at least one of the following:

- In *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Code Minings*** uncheck *Enable code minings*
- In *Window > **Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors*** set ***Show code minings for problem annotations*** to ***None***

The first preference is enabled by default, but the second preference is disabled by default. If you did not change the *Text Editors* preferences, the preference might have been changed by an installed plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

See [**Eclipse Documentation**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#show-markers-as-code-minings):

> You can now see the **errors, warnings, and info markers** inline in most of the text editors. No more mousing around to see the actual error message!
>
> [image: Java editor showing a warning and an error inline]
>
> You can see the available quick fixes by clicking on the message.
>
> [image: Manifest editor the quick fix menu for an error displayed inline]
>
> You can enable it on the **General > Editors > Text Editors** preference page and set **Show Code Minings for Annotations** to:
>
> - None (default)
> - Errors only
> - Errors and Warnings
> - Errors, Warnings and Info

I believe there is also a setting specifically for the **Java Editor**.